# To point domain name to IP address with port number

Tags: nginx, networking, dns

I have created one domain example.com from Freenom domain service. I have one Ubuntu server on AWS with valid IP address. In Ubuntu server installed Apache server and running one web application. When i hit the IP address with port number 8080 then it redirect to web application login panel. As same i should do that when i hit the domain name  it should redirect to web application login panel. I have to create dummy domain for this server IP. I want to point example.com to IP address with port number 8080. From wherever hit the example.com then it should redirect to my server. How to point domain name to IP address ?. Still now i created free domain example.com from Freenom domain service. So what are the steps to be done for my requirement?. Please let me know if any one know the steps to point domain name to IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a A record in your dns host provider which points `example.com` to `IP address` and add a url redirection in your web server which redirects example.com to example.com:8080 or simply serve your web through port 80.

Or another way : you can use [aws s3 to redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to point the domain name to your AWS server. Then create nginx virtual block for the domain and set it to proxy all requests to the application.

Basically, you need the following virtual block:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  }
}
```

Comment: where should i add this server block in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default ?

Comment: You can create a new server block. For example `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf` and create a symbolic link using the following command: `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. Don't forget to restart nginx for the changes to take effect.